# Dynamic serverside-rendered navbar, how to run script with CSR disabled?

Tags: svelte, server-side-rendering, sveltekit, static-site-generation

### Situation

I currently have a system set up with my SvelteKit site where during pre-rendering, a server-side library collects a directory listing of my site by using the node's `fs` library.  I then use this object to dynamically populate certain areas of the site, like the navbar.

My site is hosted out of Github Pages, so real serverside rendering isn't an option.

### Issue

It seems after doing hours of research that keeping the pre-rendered server content is mutually exclusive with running any sort of script on the client, which is now a problem since I want to dynamically fetch code from my github to showcase on a specific subpage.

Either I disable CSR (or the hydration step throws an error, to the same effect), or I'm forced to overwrite the pre-rendered content with something the client can come up with—I.E. *not* anything derived from the directory listing I could make on the server.

### Desired Solution

Jerryrigging something to try and preserve the server-generated content through the hydration seems like a *worse* idea, since according to my understanding of how Svelte works, that pre-rendered server content only gets sent for the very first page you visit.  Once CSR kicks in, no more pre-rendered content comes through.

Thus, I'm looking for a way to disable CSR while still allowing myself some way to run scripts on the client for certain components.  Any advice or help from actual experts on Svelte would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you able to share the repo?

Comment: Repo is located at https://github.com/Fasteroid/svelte-portfolio, but I'd ideally just like a minimally working example of how to get serverside prerendered content to the client without overwriting it.

Comment: Perhaps you could move this logic into a build time script that outputs an array of your routes to a file? Then import the file in your navbar.

Comment: @alexvdvalk Do you know how to implement that in full?  I'm a bit lost.

Comment: I'm a little confused on what you actually want to accomplish here. You want to "keep the pre-rendered content", but GitHub pages can't do SSR, so what would do the pre-rendering here? Why would you want to disable CSR?

Comment: I think the idea is to use fs to traverse the filesystem and build and array of all the routes instead of hard coding them into the navbar.

Comment: @superbadcodemonkey sveltekit can do ssg for github pages, see this:
https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/adapter-static
I don't really want to use clientside routing (CSR?) since it's just more javascript and more chance for something to break—but I still want interactivity/js for some components.

Comment: @Fasteroid I was about to suggest SSG, but the phrasing of your original question hints at a misunderstanding of how (SvelteKit's) SSR/CSR/SSG works. I'd recommend watching Rich Harris' talk [Have SPA's Ruined the Web?](https://youtu.be/860d8usGC0o?si=1v-9YLqD2gafcjD7), it's a great overview of all these mechanics, their pros/cons and how SvelteKit uses them to your advantage!

Comment: @superbadcodemonkey I'm bad at picking out details—could you help me understand by explaining the significance of the talk you linked?  I'm just trying to get my fs-traversed navbar to work without crippling JavaScript on the client.  Perhaps this is out-of-scope for StackOverflow.